# Why extend method is not putting puts value

Tags: ruby, inheritance

```
module Lab
  def self.foo
    puts 'foo from lab'
  end
end

module M
  def foo
    puts 'foo from module'
    super
  end
end

module Lab
  extend M
end

Lab.foo
```

I was expecting that I would see

```
foo from module
foo from lab
```

However what I am getting is

```
foo from lab
```

What I am trying to do is to intercept the value of a method from  a gem and do something.  I can use alias_method_chain but I am trying not to use that.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it was incorrect (and for some reason people were upvoting it anyways). To keep people from thinking what I thought: neither method in the code above is an instance method (because of how `extend` works).

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting

```
foo from module
foo from lab
```

Then you need to put *super* in Lab#foo, like so:

```
module Lab
  def self.foo
    super
    puts 'foo from lab'
  end
end

module M
  def foo
    puts 'foo from module'
  end
end

module Lab
  extend M
end

Lab.foo
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods defined on `Lab` directly take precedence over the methods defined in modules such as `M` that `Lab` extends.

So the `foo` defined directly on `Lab` takes precedence over `M#foo`, even though `Lab.extend M`.

To get what you want, do this:

```
module Lab
  module HasFoo
    # foo isn't defined directly on Lab directly anymore;
    # instead, it is defined in a separate module that
    # Lab extends
    def foo
      puts "foo from lab"
    end
  end

  extend HasFoo
end

module M
  def foo
    puts "foo from module"
    super
  end
end

module Lab
  # when Lab extends another module with foo, that changes
  # which concrete method the name foo gets resolved to
  extend M
end

# now you should see the module foo and then the lab foo
Lab.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include/extend a module `M` to a class `C`, and call a method `C#method` or `C.method` that is also defined for `M`, then `C` has priority over `M` in the search path of the method. In other words, you cannot overwrite a method by include/extend. You can only add new methods. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645398/ruby-include-question) related question.

In your case, `Lab.foo` is simply called. The following (without `Lab.foo`) will give you the desired result.

```
module M
  def foo
    puts 'foo from module'
  end
end

module Lab
  extend M
end

Lab.foo

# => foo from module
```

Note that your `M`'s superclass is `Module`, and since `Module#foo` is not defined, the following will cause an error.

```
module M
  def foo
    puts 'foo from module'
    super
  end
end

module Lab
  extend M
end

Lab.foo

# => method undefined error
```